# How can I make a for loop that will display 8 TextFields in javaFx

Tags: java, for-loop, javafx, textfield

This is currently the code that I have so far...

```
int nums = 8;
for (int j = 0; j < nums; j++) {
   TextField test = new TextField();
   test.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
}
this.getChildren().add(test);
```

I have tried doing somehting like TextField 'test' + j = new TextField(); so that it would create test1, test2, test3 ect. but that gave syntax errors. Not really sure on how I would go about this in any other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add them to something that allows them to stack vertically. Also, make sure your call to add them is inside the loop where `test` is still in scope.

```
VBox box = new VBox(5);
int nums = 8;
for (int j = 0; j < nums; j++) {
   TextField test = new TextField();
   test.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
   box.getChildren().add(test);
}
this.getChildren().add(box);
```

Comment: Thanks this fixed the issue. Now I guess my only issue would be that later in my program I would like to get the value of each separate TextField. If they are all labeled test how will I be able to differentiate them.

Comment: In the loop you could add the TextFields to a map or list and then reference them later on. Feel free to ask a separate question for that, but please mark my answer as the accepted answer if you feel it answered your original question. Thanks!

Comment: Create your event handlers in the loop.

Answer (score 3):

You have to move `this.getChildren().add(test);` inside the `for`-loop:

```java
int nums = 8;
for (int j = 0; j < nums; j++) {
   TextField test = new TextField();
   test.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
   this.getChildren().add(test);
}
```

Comment: Thank You @ysakhno The probelm is that only one textField displays while I would like 8 to display

Comment: I believe, there _are_ 8, they are just one under another, and you see just the top one.

Comment: @TSoVz check my answer for the solution to your stacking issue. Are you using a StackPane, what are you adding the TextFields to?

Answer (score 0):

@Dustin R's answer is great. I am just adding more. Like how to any an event on each `TextField` created.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TestingGroundsTwo extends Application
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)
    {
        VBox root = new VBox();

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            TextField tempTextField = new TextField();//Create the TextField.
            final int t = i;
            tempTextField.setPromptText("I am TextField " + t);//Set prompt text to easily identify TextField
            //Create key handlding event on the TextField
            tempTextField.setOnKeyReleased((event) -> {
                System.out.println("You typed " + event.getCode() + " in TextField " + t + ". My text value is " + tempTextField.getText());
            });
            root.getChildren().add(tempTextField);//Add the TextField to a parent node. In this case VBox.
        }

        Platform.runLater(() -> root.requestFocus());
        stage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 750, 600);
        scene.setFill(Color.GHOSTWHITE);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```